# How to filter rows in pandas dataframed

Tags: pandas

Confused.

Here's a dataset.

```
Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 1  Admissions  Number of admissions per 100,000 population6    Unnamed: 4  Admissions.1    Number of admissions per 100,000 population6.1  Unnamed: 7  Admissions.2    Number of admissions per 100,000 population6.2  ... Unnamed: 28 Admissions.9    Number of admissions per 100,000 population6.9  Unnamed: 31 Admissions.10   Number of admissions per 100,000 population6.10 Unnamed: 34 Admissions.11   Number of admissions per 100,000 population6.11 Unnamed: 37
0   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   E92000001   ENGLAND7    976420.0    1810.0  NaN 713550.0    2810.0  NaN 262870.0    940.0   ... NaN 841760  1620    NaN 614050  2530    NaN 227710  840 NaN
2   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   NaN Unknown 5100.0  0.0 NaN 4360.0  0.0 NaN 730.0   0.0 ... NaN 5220    0   NaN 4460    0   NaN 760 0   NaN
4   NaN 1   2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0
```

My code to transform it is:

```
df = pd.read_excel("LAPE_Statistical_Tables_for_England_2021.xlsx", sheet_name="1.3", skiprows=5, skipfooter=24)
df = (
    df.dropna(how="all", axis="columns"),
    df.dropna(how="all", axis="rows"),
    # Filter rows where "Unnamed: 1" column contains all uppercase characters using pd.query()
    df.dropna(subset=["Unnamed: 1"], how="any")
)

df = pd.concat(df)

# Reset the index if needed
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df
```

But why does it not remove the NaNs where column 1 is clearly contains NaN. I also want to remove the rows where column 1 is all uppercase.

Why does this not work?

Comment: can you provide minimal example with code? your example seems head of excel file, so hard to reproduce. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of issues in the code. The parentheses create a tuple instead of modifying the original DataFrame df and instead of concatenating a tuple (df), concatenate the individual DataFrames resulting from the previous operations to resolve the error.

I have considered first two columns and Here's the corrected code:

```
df = pd.read_excel("test1.xlsx")
df = df.dropna(how="all", axis="columns")  # Remove columns with all NaN values
df = df.dropna(how="all", axis="rows")     # Remove rows with all NaN values

# Filter rows where "Unnamed: 1" column contains all uppercase characters using pd.query()
df = df.dropna(subset=["Unnamed: 1"], how="any")

# Reset the index if needed
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output using your code:**

```
df

Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 1
0   NaN
1   E92000001
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   NaN
0   NaN
1   E92000001
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   NaN
1   E92000001
```

**Output after applying my modifications:**

```
Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 1
1   E92000001
```

Comment: I feel like this is chatgpt answer